# Log4j compatibility/bridge API class cast exception

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to migrate some legacy code to log4j 2.6 via the 1.x => 2.x bridge jar.

In the old code, I have a class that extends org.apache.log4j.Logger.  When adding the 2.6 core/api jars as well as the bridge api jar to my classpath, I have a unit test that is failing due to a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.Logger cannot be cast to com.example.MyLogger
```

and the class signature of MyLogger is

```
package com.example;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class MyLogger extends Logger {
}
```

It works with just log4j 1.2, and the old class (org.apache.log4j.Logger) is in the bridge jar and since MyLogger isa Logger, you'd expect it would still work.

Any ideas on why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening at run-time because the code is manipulating a Logger object that is not an instance of MyLogger.  I would first check if I were constructing only MyLogger instances in the code.  A debugger helps here, as does [avoiding the use of printStackTrace](/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice).